# Async http call in custom listview

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have question regardin async http call in my custom listview. How do i call async call in my following custom Listview and parse json to fill the Listview . My Custom Listview is contain from images and text.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ListActivityS extends ListActivity 
{

    private GetHttpCall getCall;


    String item[];
    int id[];


    ArrayList<Video> videos;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        //Crearte instance to http call
        getCall=new GetHttpCall();
        String response=null;
        try {
            response=getCall.connect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JSONParser _parser=new JSONParser();
        _parser.parseHttpJson(response);

        item = JSONParser.num_title;
        id=JSONParser.num_id;

        videos=new ArrayList<Video>();


         for(int i=0;i<item.length;i++)
         {
             Video vid=new Video();
             vid.setTitle(item[i]);
             vid.setId(id[i]);

             videos.add(vid);
         }

        getListView().setDividerHeight(2);

        getListView().setAdapter(new BindDataAdapter(this, videos));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(item[position] + " is clicked.");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
        builder.show();
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_list, menu);
        return true;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Call `new AsyncAction().execute(null, null, null);`

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(item[position] + " is clicked.");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
        builder.show();
    }


private class AsyncAction extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        public boolean status = false;
        private ProgressDialog pd;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {


                status = true;

//Crearte instance to http call
        getCall=new GetHttpCall();
        String response=null;
        try {
            response=getCall.connect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JSONParser _parser=new JSONParser();
        _parser.parseHttpJson(response);

        item = JSONParser.num_title;
        id=JSONParser.num_id;

        videos=new ArrayList<Video>();


         for(int i=0;i<item.length;i++)
         {
             Video vid=new Video();
             vid.setTitle(item[i]);
             vid.setId(id[i]);

             videos.add(vid);
         }

        getListView().setDividerHeight(2);



            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            pd.dismiss();

             getListView().setAdapter(new BindDataAdapter(this, videos));

        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd = new ProgressDialog(listmessages.this);
            pd.setMessage("loading...");
            pd.setIndeterminate(true);
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();
        }

    }



        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're starting a get http request in the on create, it's bad. The request should be executed in a separate thread like in an asynctask.

- In the on create, initialize the list with a temporary item (like a progress item).
- In the on create, start an async task, 
  -- In the asynctask, in the doBackground, execute the request
  -- In the asynctask, in the onPostExecute, remove the temporary item and add your item results.

I can provide some code if you need but there's so much good examples all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

refer [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) and [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/build-a-twitter-search-app-fetch-parse-the-twitter-json-feed/) .. In that tutorial they will use AsyncTask to fetch the JSON tweets, parse them, then display them within the ListView..

thry are using AsyncTask to carry out the fetching, parsing and displaying of the tweet feed on the user search query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an `AsyncTask` for downloading the data you will display and then actually displaying that information by updating the list adapter and thus the `ListView`

```
private GetStuff extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Param . . . params){
        //Do all you i/o stuff like downloading content here
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(){
        //update your list adapter here
    }
}
```

You can [read more about AsyncTask here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) if you want. The idea when using it to update a list view is as follows.

(1) perform all i/o functions within `doInBackground`. This isn't a choice so much as it is a requirement since Jellybean forward. Anything involving i/o must be in the background. Also it is a good practice to process any bitmaps or other content here as well since it avoids blocking the UI thread. Get your content and process it here.

(2) update the `ListView` in onPostExecute. Within the `AsyncTask` structure `onPostExecute` runs whatever methods you include here on the UI thread once `doInBackround` has finished. Since you must update the `ListView` from the UI thread the method you use for updating the adapter and notifying of a data set change must go here.

(3) create a new task and execute it in your activity. When ever you want the download and update process to start you need to add th following

```
GetStuff get = new GetStuff();
get.execute();
```

this will actually start the task running.

That's it, you can tweek the implimentation to fit your needs depending on whether you need to pass things from the different `AsyncTask` methods or to the task itself.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to go through the basics of `ListView` and `AsyncTask`.

There are some basic mistakes in your approach like

> How do i call async call in my following custom Listview and parse
>   json to fill the Listview

One does not call an `AsyncTask` from a `ListView` to fill the `ListView` itself. Best practice says that you always call AsyncTask on user generated events like Button clicks and when you get response on `PostExecute` of `AsyncTask`,launch a ListViewActivity from there!

Here are some good tutorials:

- [**Load ListView in background AsyncTask**](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/07/load-listview-in-background-asynctask.html)
- [**Android AsyncTask Example**](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-asynctask-example.html)